# ffmpeg - video with timer

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am currently working with the `drawtext` and `drawbox` filters to recreate a similar video appearance to what is shown below in the image. I am trying to see of a possible ways to add a count down timer to display video duration. The timer could either be placed in the upper left or right hand corners.

I am able to generate a test video showing a timer this way: `ffplay -f lavfi -i testsrc` OR  `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -vf crop=29:52:256:94 -t 10 timer1.mp4`. However, how can I display a timer?

**drawbox/drawtext filter settings**

```
ffmpeg -i "/media/test/test.mp4" -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf:text='Title of this Video':x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h-th)/2"  /media/test_edited.mp4"
```

**desired output**

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Why did you remove the image showing the desired output? Without it, the question is totally unclear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible but will require scripting. `ffprobe` will be used to determine the duration of the input, then the countdown and background box will be created by the [`drawtext`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter.

[image: reverse duration countdown timer]
<sub>A 30 second input will start from 30 and count down to 0.</sub>

Example:

```
input=input.mp4
duration=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$input")
ffmpeg -i "$input" -vf "drawtext=fontfile=OpenSans-Regular.ttf:text='%{eif\:$duration-t\:d}':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=w-tw-20:y=th:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=10,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- If you prefer rounded corners you may be able to make a PNG file with alpha, and then place it in your desired location using the [`overlay`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filter. Doesn't seem worth it to me though.
- If you find the duration from `ffprobe` to be inaccurate then you will have to completely decode the file to get the actual duration and then parse the console output. One method would be: `ffmpeg -i input -f null -`.
- This may be possible to do without `ffprobe` but I don't have an alternative method at the moment.
- You can combine this filterchain with the one from [ffmpeg drawtext filter - create transparent background with text](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/15554/1760) to get exactly what you want. An oversimplified command could then look like:

  ```
  -vf "format,drawbox,drawtext,drawtext,format"
  ```

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student It will vary in width according to the number of digits. If that's annoying then dump all of the box related stuff from `drawtext` and make another box with `drawbox` instead. If you want to keep using the current method with `drawtext` then `boxborderw` will control the "padding", but you can't independently control top, right, bottom, and left like you can in CSS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23855/discussion-between-lordneckbeard-and-code-ed-student).

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am sticking with just having it in `drawtext`. I just increased the `boxborderw` to ultimately get what I needed it. Thanks for all the help! what are the coordinates to place timer in the left corner?

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student Top left? That's the easy one because that's the default. You can probably use `boxborderw` + whatever margin you want, so if `boxborderw` is 10, and you want a 10 pixel margin separating the box from the left and top edges, then `x=20:y=20` or `x=20:y=x`. You will have to experiment.

Comment: I have another ffmpeg question in relation to crossfading: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15740/crossfading-audio-at-beginning-and-ending-of-video

Comment: @llogan probably need your help over here: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/26036/translate-ffmpeg-drawtext-bash-code-to-batch

Comment: @Arete Unfortunately I know nothing of Windows batch file scripting.